# Freeing memory from mremap segmentation faults

Tags: c, mmap

What are the rules for freeing memory that has been changed via `mremap(2)`? Experimentation suggests that if the address passed to `mremap()` is the same one returned, then `free()` will work. But if the address returned is different, `free()` will produce a segmentation fault. For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <malloc.h>

#define __USE_GNU
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define ALLOC_SIZE (1024 * 1024)

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        void *m = NULL, *tmp;
        size_t size = 4 * ALLOC_SIZE;

        m = memalign(4096, size);
        if (m == NULL)
                return EXIT_FAILURE;

        tmp = mremap(m, size, size + ALLOC_SIZE, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);

        if (tmp == MAP_FAILED) {
                printf("mremap(%p, %zu, %zu, MREMAP_MAYMOVE) failed\n",
                                m, size, size+ALLOC_SIZE);
        } else {
                if (tmp != m) {
                        printf("Memory moved from %p to %p\n", m, tmp);
                        m = tmp;
                }

                size += ALLOC_SIZE;
        }

        printf("Freeing %zu bytes from %p\n", size, m);
        free(m);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

will segfault unless

- the `MREMAP_MAYMOVE` is removed
- `free` is changed to `munmap`

If the answer is to not use `memalign` family of functions and instead `mmap` anonymous memory, can you point to a man page or similar which says this is the case?

Comment: What kind of insane person would `mremap` something that was effectively `malloc`ed?

Comment: @EOF, like I hinted, that may be the crux of the question. But the mremap man page doesn't say that you cannot do this.

Comment: `mmap` is a lower-level primitive (syscall-level, specified by POSIX) than `malloc` (C library, specified by the C standard). They don't mix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page for free (`man 3 free`):

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc(), or realloc(). Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been called before, undefined behavior occurs.

Basically using free on memory which is not allocated by malloc family is undefined. Since you are using mremap as the last function to allocate memory, it is not malloc allocated memory.

You have to use munmap here after the mremap. Also, you shouldn't be mixing the malloc family with mmap family. That is just a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Worth pointing out that `mremap`ing `malloc`ed memory is going to end horribly even without attempting to `free` that specific allocation. The next `malloc` will also be exciting...